# rails - assets_host routing issue for png file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, asset-pipeline

I have a QRCode generator that generates a .png file.

The path for the qrcode generator is the SHOW method with the PNG mime type.

I'm using assets_sync :

```
# Asset Sync
  config.action_controller.asset_host = "https://#{ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']}.s3.amazonaws.com"
```

And when requesting the PNG,  i get redirected to:

```
https://mysite-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/restaurants/50f17f4137ff3ef955000001.png
```

but I need:

```
https://mysite.com/restaurants/50f17f4137ff3ef955000001.png
```

The routing I'm using, though very ugly, is:

```
<%= image_tag(restaurant_path(restaurant)+".png") %>
```

Comment: This is what `asset_host` does. It tells Rails how to build URLs to your assets. By specifying an S3 host, all of your asset paths will output that as the path to your assets. I'm not sure what you expected to happen.

Comment: Although this is a png file, it's not an asset as it's generated upon request. I want to override the url so I can get the right one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, I just had to use:

```
<%= image_tag(restaurant_url(restaurant)+".png") %>
```

URL instead of path.

Answer (score 0):

slightly less ugly (to my eyes) might be:

```
<%= "#{image_tag restaurant_url(restaurant)}.url" %>
```